# How to perform a Linear Regression by group in PySpark?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, linear-regression, apache-spark-ml

The goal is to perform linear regression for each user in a scalable way in PySpark. Features: `x1` and `x2`. Output: `y`

Regression equation (zero intercept): `y = m(x1) + n(x2)`

Example:

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "user": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        "x1": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
        "x2": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        "y": [2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9],
    }
)
df = sc.createDataFrame(pdf)
df.show()
```

Data looks like:

```
+----+---+---+---+
|user| x1| x2|  y|
+----+---+---+---+
|   1|  1|  2|  2|
|   1|  2|  3|  4|
|   1|  3|  4|  6|
|   2|  1|  5|  3|
|   2|  2|  6|  6|
|   2|  3|  7|  9|
+----+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used PandasUDF, that works for my use case. Ben Webber explains it in his [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-methods-for-parallelization-in-spark-6a1a4333b473#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20newer%20features,one%20large%20Spark%20data%20frame.)

from his post we can take the following approach: (BDR:6.4;Spark:2.4.5)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "user": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        "x1": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
        "x2": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        "y": [2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9],
    }
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
   
schema = StructType([StructField('user', DoubleType(), True),
                     StructField('r_squared', DoubleType(), True)])  

@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def train_LR(input_pd):
    usr = input_pd.iloc[0]['user']
    # Implement lineal regression, as per your needs
    model = sm.OLS(input_pd['y'], input_pd[['x1','x2']]).fit()
    R_sq = model.rsquared
    return pd.DataFrame({'user': usr, 'r_squared': R_sq }, index=[0])

results = df.groupby('user').apply(train_LR)
display(results)
```

Note that the UDF is getting a pandas dataframe with only the data for the groupby